# Use R to write .xlsm file, after using openxlsm to read in a xlsm file

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

Here's what I've got:

```
datDir<-directory<-dirmm <- getwd()
args <- c(dir)
setwd(args[1])
files <-  list.files(datDir, pattern = ".xls",full.names=F)
input_Excel<- 
  files[1]
library(openxlsx) 

#input_Excel <- "foo.xlsm"
wb <- loadWorkbook(paste0(dirmm,"\\", input_Excel)) 
writeData(wb, "sheet 1", "namething", startCol = 2, startRow = 1)

 saveWorkbook(wb, overwrite = TRUE, file = paste0(dir, "\\", namer".xlsm"))
 saveWorkbook(wb, overwrite = TRUE, file = paste0(dir, "\\", namer".xlsx"))
```

But everytime I hit go, and try to open with Excel, I get told:
saved as xlsx: "The workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrupt"
saved as xlsm: "because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file".

Comment: You could give `openxlsx2` a try. `wb_load("file.xlsm")$add_data("sheet 1", x = "namething")$open()`

Comment: Also,  xls files are NOT the same format as xlsx. Are you sure that the file is xlsx and not xls like it says?

Comment: @G5W - Yes. File is a .xlsm when I read it in, and needs to be written out as an .xlsm to preserve a macro.